# Discrete Fourier Transform and uneven sampling

Tags: frequency, fourier-transform

In this [blog article](http://tamino.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/sampling-rate/)
an example is given of one can use the DFT to detect frequencies much higher than the sample rate.
In the comments sections I asked how it was done, since DFT normally requires evenly sampled data. The author of the blog responded concisely with:

> One can still define the DFT as proportional to
>
> $$ X(\nu) = {1 \over N} \sum x_n e^{-i 2 \pi \nu t_n} $$

How would one do that? I am asking for advice to do exactly that.
I can replicate the example if I use the date compensated method of Ferraz-Mello [1](http://tamino.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/sampling-rate/) but the blog author says that normally DFT will work using that hint.

[1](http://tamino.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/sampling-rate/) http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1981AJ.....86..619F&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf